# Not reading a line and a while loop and I don't know why

Tags: java, while-loop

I was trying to figure out why the while loop was not working So I added print statements for `depIn1` and `value`. Why is it skipping over the line `depValue1 = Double.parseDouble(depIn1)`? If so, wouldn't the while loop still work because of the check that value is not true?

```
String depIn1 = "";
double originBalance1 = 0.00;
double newBalance1 = 0.00;
double depValue1 = 0.00;
String newNewBalance1 = "";
String originStringBalance1 = "";
boolean value;

BufferedReader depositInput1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Amount to withdraw: ");                           
depIn1 = depositInput1.readLine();
value = isInt(depIn1);
System.out.println("depIn1: " + depIn1);
System.out.println("Value: " + value);
depValue1 = Double.parseDouble(depIn1);
System.out.println("depValue1: " + depValue1);

double doubleBalanceValue = Double.parseDouble(users.get(i).getBalance());
while((depValue1 > bankBalance) || (depValue1 <= 0) || (depValue1 > doubleBalanceValue) || (value != true)){
     System.out.print("No! Invalid input! Try again! Amount to withdraw: ");     
     depIn1 = depositInput1.readLine();
     depValue1 = Double.parseDouble(depIn1);
}
System.out.println("Thanks!");
```

Current output:

```
Amount to withdraw: asfd
depIn1: asfd
Value: false
```

Comment: Why did I get docked a point for this question?

Comment: What makes you think it's skipping over the line? It can't skip over a line unless you surround it with a conditional statement. Post your actual input and output along with your expected output.

Comment: @Dukeling There's no output for `System.out.println("depValue1: " + depValue1);`. That's why I said "skipping".

Comment: What do you mean with no output ? Can you copy paste the console output plz ?

Comment: @ErwanC.There you go

Comment: The only possibilities I can see here is that the code you're running is not the same as the code you're looking at / the code you posted here (try rebuilding your code), you're getting an exception on parseDouble, which should show up in the console output (which will indeed cause the lines after it to not execute as it stands) or you're not describing the behaviour properly. You'll also need to post the input you're passing to the program.

Comment: Same as Dukeling. You should have an exception in console as you dont have any try catch

Comment: It's something to do with my isInt(depIn1) I believe. I'll figure it out. But thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String depIn1 = "";
    double originBalance1=0.00;
    double newBalance1=0.00;
    double depValue1=0.00;
    String newNewBalance1 = "";
    String originStringBalance1 = "";
    boolean value=false;

    double bankBalance = 5000.00;
    double doubleBalanceValue =5000.00;

    BufferedReader depositInput1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    do{
        System.out.print("Amount to withdraw: ");                           
        depIn1 = depositInput1.readLine();
        System.out.println("depIn1: " + depIn1);
        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
        try{
        depValue1 = Double.parseDouble(depIn1);
        value=true;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            value=false;
        }
        System.out.println("depValue1: " + depValue1);

        if(!value){
             System.out.print("No! Invalid input! Try again!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Thanks!");
        }
    }
    while((depValue1 > bankBalance) || (depValue1 <= 0) || (depValue1 > doubleBalanceValue) || (value != true));

}
```

}